# Expectation of the exponent of a constant times exiting time of a Brownian motion (i.e. $\mathbb{E}_x[e^{n\sigma}]$)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, expected-value, stopping-times

Suppose $a, n>0$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian Motion, define $$\sigma=\inf\{t:B_t\in\{-a,a\}\}.$$
I want to find $\mathbb{E}_x[e^{n\sigma}]$. (Notice since $n>0$ it is $\textbf{not}$ Laplace transform!)

I used standard methods from stochastic analysis (Ito formula + Optional Stopping Time theorem) to connect it with bounded value problem
Here is my answer 
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}_xe^{n \sigma}=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{2n}(a+x))+\sin(\sqrt{2n}(a-x))}{\sin\left(2\sqrt{2n}a\right)}
\end{align*}
which does not make sense, because it is not monotone with respect to $n$... Any help/questions/comments would be appreciated!

Edit: $x\in(-a,b)$ and $\mathbb{E}_x$ is the expectation with respect to law of Brownian Motion starting at $x$.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{E}_x$ does not make sense. $e^{n\sigma}$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson I think $E_x$ denotes expectation with respect to the law of Brownian motion started in $x$.

Comment: @Sisyphus is right, I added the edit for clarification.

Comment: Your computation is probably correct, but the result is not completely correct. How? The expectation is infinite for large $n$. (It becomes infinite after the denominator is equal to $0$.)